# Spring @Configurable with JavaConfig on GAE-Objectify classes

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, objectify, spring-java-config

I have such an Objectify Entity class

```
@Entity
@Cache
@Index
public class DummyEntity {
    @Id private Long id;
    private ObjectifyStartup objectifyStartup;
    private String someData;
    //Getters and setters for all
}
```

This `ObjectifyStartup` is a bean initialized in Web MVC JavaConfig file which I need to be injected into any `DummyEntity` instance

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class SpringWebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ObjectifyStartup objectifyStartup() { return new ObjectifyStartupImpl(); }
}
```

I want to do this somewhere in the code, basically in a controller

```
DummyEntity newDummy = new DummyEntity();
```

I know I need to use `@Configurable` annotation on the `DummyEntity` to make the Spring container inject the dependency, but what is the JavaConfig code I have to put into `SpringWebMvcConfig` class for this DI to work?

I cannot use Autowiring, Component Scans because of the performance hit in GAE due to Autowiring from best practices mentioned here [Spring GAE Optimization](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/spring_optimization) . And all the solutions I have encountered uses `@Autowired` with `@ComponentScan` with `<context:spring-configured/>`. Kindly provide a solution that uses subjective declarations than autowiring.

Answer (score 1):

After quite some time since I asked this question, I changed the strategy and I am now not initializing a `ObjectifyStartup` bean to provide me with `ofy()` service, as from Objectify Docs it is not advisable to create an instance of `ofy()` and using it pan-application. I was doing it so here because in the `ObjectifyStartup` bean I was registering all my Entities with the Objectify and then getting hold of its bean instantiation to do datastore operations. But now I have moved the Entities registration to a static block that executes with Spring bootstraps my application.